# Exchange 2003 > 2010 Migration

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, public-folders, calendar

I have an Exchange migration in progress at the moment.

A few users are on Exchange 2010 and most of them are still on 2003.

Now, the issue is that things like calendars can't be viewed across 2003 and 2010 users. 2003 users can only access other 2003 calendars and such.

I expect that this is because the public folders aren't being replicated.

Does anyone have any idea how I can replicate the public folders from 2003 to 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has docs [describing the procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691120.aspx) in both the GUI and from PowerShell. This assumes you're using Exchange 2010 SP1 (which you really should be). You'll need a public folder database on the E2K10 server to replicate into, obviously. You can [background about creating one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335208.aspx) from Microsoft, too.

Once you've got the database created and configured replication it's pretty much "fire and forget". If you're not using public folders for anything else in your E2K3 organization then you can think about migrating away from them altogether once you've gotten rid of E2K3.